# Selenium chrome browser colaborate with Phantom wallet

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, solana

Comunication and interaction in Phantom wallet extension

Hello guys! I try to make something like a trading bot with the Selenium, but there are some problems. I use the **driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'')** command for the website, but I need to open Phantom Wallet Chrome extension--->write the password--> submit transaction. Does anybody know how to do it? Because if I integrate the extension to the "automated chrome" I still must write a seed phrase and it still don't work. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.